# php url and folder name

Tags: php, url, mamp

I just installed the latest MAMP on Mac, and found this hard to understand:
The document root seems to be "~/MAMP/htdocs", because "localhost" will open the `index.php` file under this folder.[image]

However, "localhost/MAMP/?language=English" opens "~/MAMP/bin/mamp/index.php". I know that in URL strings between "/"s are not necessaries folders, but if they are not folders, how was it constructed and how does the system know where to find the right files?

I know this is a pretty basic question which I can probably get answers by myself, but I don't know what key word to search. Tried "php url construction" and "php url folder" but no luck. So a proper keyword suggestion is also appreciated.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is setup by default by MAMP. If you open up `MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf` in a text editor and scroll down to around line 368/369 and specifically line 408 you will see that it is an Apache Alias. it is setup for easy navigation, instead of having to type http://localhost:8888/bin/mamp you can just type http://localhost:8888/MAMP. It is also setup as an Alias to ensure that you can still access the web tools if you change the document root from something other than `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs`.

Are you sure http://localhost:8888 has the docroot set to `~/MAMP/htdocs` as you suggest? Reason I ask is that looking at your first image the text says the docroot is `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs`. Also the docs say it should be in the `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs`. I think the issue is that you do not have MAMP in the Applications folder where it needs to be.

https://www.mamp.info/en/documentation/

> **Where should I store my HTML and PHP pages?**
>
> By default, PHP and HTML Pages should be stored inside the MAMP
>   "htdocs" folder which is located in the MAMP Application directory
>   /Applications/MAMP. This folder is called "Document Root". You can
>   change the path for the Document Root in the MAMP application's
>   Preferences Panel:

Also please note this https://www.mamp.info/en/documentation/#q8

> **Will MAMP work if the MAMP folder is not located in the Applications
>   directory?**
>
> No. In order to work properly the MAMP folder has to be located in the
>   Applications folder.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the `~` doesn't mean home folder, but `/Application` in this case, I was just being lazy.

Comment: It is proved that in my machine `localhost` = `MAMP/htdocs/index.php`, and `localhost/MAMP/?language=English` = `MAMP/bin/mamp/index.php`(I edited both files and the pages change respectively). So there is actually no issue here(everything is working), it is just me not understanding how the URL is constructed.

Comment: I believe both of those are just VHOSTS. The 2nd one is setup so you can access mamp specific configuration scripts. For example phpmyadmin is found under the 2nd URL.

Comment: Path To Webstart
The default MAMP start page provides links to access utilities such as phpMyAdmin, ...

Using the default setting (/MAMP/), you will be directed to the MAMP PRO utilities start page using the Alias definition /MAMP/. If this field is left blank, you will be taken to your default document root (http://localhost:8888 in the /Applications/MAMP/htdocs). If you enter /subDirectory in this field, you will be taken to the /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/subDirectory folder via your default web browser (http://localhost:8888/subDirectory).

Comment: I understand the 2nd half about subDirectory. But what is "Alias definition"? And how does the server know where to find right file when the url is "..../MAMP/...."?

Comment: It is setup by default by MAMP. If you open up MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf in a text editor and scroll down to around line 368/369 and specifically line 408 you will see that it is an apache Alias. Like I mentioned before, it is setup by MAMP to provide you with a way to access the web scripts and admin tools such as phpMyAdmin.

Comment: I would not focus on this, as it is not an issue and the software is working as expected. The reason is outlined above, but if you don't understand then just know that MAMP configured the URL /MAMP/ to point to /Applications/MAMP/bin/mamp so you do not have to type /bin/mamp/ in the URL, instead you can just type /MAMP/. Also if these Aliases were not configured and you changed the root directory through the MAMP application then you would not be able to access the web tools.

Comment: Thanks. "MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf" this is the answer I am seeking